# How to show sell price when tax rate is added using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

Hi guys can someone help me about my problem. The problem is when I put a value on the Buy Price and Tax rate column it didn't show the result on the sell price input box.

This my function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function final_total(count){
        var final_product_amount = 0;
        for(j=1;j<=count;j++){
            var quantity = 0;
            var buy_price = 0;
            var sell_price = 0;
            var tax_rate = 0;
            var total_amount = 0;
            var total_sell = 0;
            var actual_amount = 0;
            var total_tax = 0;
            var min_qty = 0;
            quantity = $('#quantity'+j).val();
            if(quantity>0){
                buy_price = $('#buy_price'+j).val().replace(",","");
                if(buy_price > 0 ){
                    total_amount = parseFloat(quantity) * parseFloat(buy_price);
                    $('#total_amount'+j).val('P '+total_amount);
                    tax_rate = $('#tax_rate'+j).val();
                    if(tax_rate>0){ 
                        total_sell = parseFloat(buy_price) * parseFloat(tax_rate)/100;
                        total_tax = parseFloat(buy_price) + parseFloat(total_sell);
                        $('#sell_price'+j).val('P '+total_tax);
                    }               
                }
                actual_amount = $('#total_amount'+j).val().replace("P ","");
                final_product_amount = parseFloat(final_product_amount) + parseFloat(actual_amount);    
            }
        }
        $('#final_total_amount').text('₱ '+final_product_amount);
    }
}
```

I tried modifying the code but it did not show when I finished inputting some value on tax rate. When I clicked the + button and filling the input filled, the sell price on the first row is being filled and working. It only works when new table row is filled. Hope someone can help me about this one. Thanks.

Comment: This is a fairly long function, generally making your logic hard to follow. As an indirect answer I'd recommend you begin solving this by breaking down your code into smaller more modular functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `onblur` function to calculate selling price on both `textbox` buy_price and tax_rate.
[onblur jquery api](https://api.jquery.com/blur/).

Below code snippet is to show how you can utilize the `onblur` function to calculate selling price and grand total amount.

```js
function calculateSellPrice(_i) {
   var _buyPrice = $("#txtBuyPrice-" + _i).val();
   var _tax = $("#txtTax-" + _i).val();
   var _sellPrice = 0;
   
   if(_buyPrice != "" && _tax != "") {
    _sellPrice = parseFloat(_buyPrice) + parseFloat(_tax);
    
    $("#txtSellPrice-" + _i).val(_sellPrice);
   }
   
   calculateTotal();
  }
  
  function calculateTotal() {
  
   var count = 2;
   
   var totalAmount = 0;
   
   for(var j=1; j<=count; j++) {
    var sellingPrice = $("#txtSellPrice-" + j).val();
    if(sellingPrice != "")
     totalAmount += parseFloat(sellingPrice);
   }
   
   $("#lblGrandTotal").text("Grand Total: " + totalAmount);
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <td>Sl.No</td>
    <td>Product</td>
    <td>Buy Price</td>
    <td>Tax</td>
    <td>Sell Price</td>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>
     <select id="prod-1">
      <option>Select</option>
      <option value="1">Product 1</option>
      <option value="2">Product 2</option>
      <option value="3">Product 3</option>
      <option value="4">Product 4</option>
     </select>
    </td>
    <td>
     <input type="text" id="txtBuyPrice-1" value="" placeholder="Buy Price" onblur="calculateSellPrice(1);" />
    </td>
    <td>
     <input type="text" id="txtTax-1" value="" placeholder="Tax" onblur="calculateSellPrice(1);" />
    </td>
    <td>
     <input type="text" id="txtSellPrice-1" value="" placeholder="Sell Price" disabled />
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>
     <select id="prod-2">
      <option>Select</option>
      <option value="1">Product 1</option>
      <option value="2">Product 2</option>
      <option value="3">Product 3</option>
      <option value="4">Product 4</option>
     </select>
    </td>
    <td>
     <input type="text" id="txtBuyPrice-2" value="" placeholder="Buy Price" onblur="calculateSellPrice(2);" />
    </td>
    <td>
     <input type="text" id="txtTax-2" value="" placeholder="Tax" onblur="calculateSellPrice(2);" />
    </td>
    <td>
     <input type="text" id="txtSellPrice-2" value="" placeholder="Sell Price" disabled />
    </td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
   <tr>
    <td colspan="5" style="text-align: right;">
     <label id="lblGrandTotal">Grand Total: 0</label>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </tfoot>
 </table>
 
</body>
</html>
```